# (SOLVED) this.axios is undefined in production (vue-cli build)

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue and trying to build my test project with vue-cli.

I'm using axios for API calls and everything work fine in dev mode (localhost) but when I'm trying to build and use it in production it doesn't work...

I got the error :

```
[Vue warn]: Error in beforeCreate hook: "TypeError: this.axios is undefined"
```

in my main.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import App from './App.vue'


Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
```

In my components I call axios with `this.axios`

I also have a last question, after running `vue-cli-service build` what are the generated output files **app.5eah9a5.js** and **chunk-vendors.6eah5ae65h.js** ?

Why it doesn't generate a simple .js file to include ? 
Excuse my ignorance, I'm new to Webpack and all the front end stuff

Many thanks

**EDIT:** I forgot to add the defer attribute on the script tag, it works now

Comment: Are you making a API request in a beforeCreate hook ?

Comment: Hi, it was me, I forgot to add the defer attribute to the script tag, shame on me lol. 
Also at first I tried with vue-cli-service build --target lib and I didn't understand the --target flag but now I understand